# Cannot install MELPA package in Emacs

Tags: emacs, melpa

I'm new to emacs and trying to install the `smartparens` package from MELPA.
I have the package installed (I'm pretty sure) [image]

The next step in the docs is to run `(require 'smartparens-config)`. I put this in my `~/.emacs`, but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried `M-x require 'smartparens-config`, but it says there is `[No match]` for `require`.
Not sure how to proceed here

Answer (score 1):

You should include `(package-initialize)` in your init file, before you're calling `(require 'smartparens-config)`